# Mapping software to find route using KML (or GPX) file with lots of paths

Tags: openstreetmap, mapping, google-maps, kml

I have a large KML file (I also have it in GPX format but I've been using the KML so far) with LOTS of walking paths in it, criss-crossing most of France (mostly the GR routes but with a couple of others). I have imported it and been able to view it happily in both Google Maps and Google Earth.

When I ask Google for directions between 2 points on these paths, it ignores them and uses paths/roads etc that it knows about. What I'd like it to do essentially is replace the built-in roads with my KML paths, and find me the a route along those instead.

Is there any mapping software capable of this?

MacOS would be the preferred target, but I'm happy with any OS as I'm on a Mac with windows on bootcamp and a few Linux VMs. Free solutions would be great; as for paid solutions I'd rather not set any boundaries, as though I wouldn't actually pay beyond a small fee to do this (I can do it by hand if I need to after all), I'd be interested to know that such software existed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case for using [GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/) with [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/about/index.html) as a front end with possibly a plugin or two. *(Note that you can probably get more help over at https://gis.stackexchange.com/).*

GRASS GIS:

> GRASS GIS, commonly referred to as GRASS (Geographic Resources
>   Analysis Support System), is a free and open source Geographic
>   Information System (GIS) software suite used for geospatial data
>   management and analysis, image processing, graphics and maps
>   production, spatial modeling, and visualization.

QGIS:

> QGIS is a professional GIS application that is built on top of and
>   proud to be itself Free and Open Source Software (FOSS).

Both:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform *including Mac*
- Can use data from multiple sources such as Open Streetmaps
- Can import from multiple file types including GPX
- You can factor in information on altitude changes, *(much more significant when cycling than driving).*

You should be able to use the travelling salesman algorithm with selected layers. An example of such usage can be seen at https://openrouteservice.org

Comment: I'm accepting now because I've convinced myself this is totally doable, just gotta learn a bit about GIS software before I get it to actually work!

Comment: @JohnCH - Please post how you get on - I am sure it will be of interest to more than just me.